# What is the correct CSS for aligning images?

Tags: html, css, image, position, alignment

I'm currently designing a website where a section has three images lined side by side. Each image is placed within it's own div. It works fine but the CSS looks congested. Can you align three images within the same div rather than having a div for each image?

```css
.subSectOne {
    position: absolute; left: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    background: url(../images/paw1.png);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.subSectTwo {
    position: absolute; left: 40%;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    background: url(../images/paw2.png);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.subSectThree {
    position: absolute; left: 60%;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    background: url(../images/paw3.png);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="subSection">  
  
                <div class="subSectOne">

                </div>
                <div class="subSectTwo">

                </div>
                <div class="subSectThree">

                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using absolute positioning and float together makes no sense – the first one “wins”, and so the second one is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, try this https://jsfiddle.net/uxvg0kod/ and its responsive

HTML

```
<div class="subSection">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.subSection {
  text-align: center;
}

.subSection img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly although I had to change: Vertical-align: Center; to 'middle' as it said it was incorrect CSS. I also had to add some padding to the images to space them out a little. Does exactly what I need and cleans up a lot of CSS. Thanks

Comment: Glad i could help, you are right about `vertical-align` it was my mistake. Also if this helped you maybe you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
<style>
    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }

    img.img {
        display: block;
        width: 30%;
        float: left;
        /* other styles */
    }

    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>   

 <div class="container">
        <img class="img img1" title="img1" src="/images/img1.png">
        <img class="img img2" title="img2" src="/images/img2.png">
        <img class="img img3" title="img3" src="/images/img3.png">
        <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a good solution for your question. I added a new class `.row` and in this class I set the **div** properties for the `background-images`.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.subSection{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

.subSectOne {
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYXNLuN8M8-f0TZUM9DIiMD3bNN6B8hyvlyttFrUdN423bn7ZD) no-repeat;
}

.subSectTwo {
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYXNLuN8M8-f0TZUM9DIiMD3bNN6B8hyvlyttFrUdN423bn7ZD) no-repeat;
}

.subSectThree {
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYXNLuN8M8-f0TZUM9DIiMD3bNN6B8hyvlyttFrUdN423bn7ZD) no-repeat;   
}

.row{
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="subSection">  
   <div class="row subSectOne"></div>
   <div class="row subSectTwo"></div>
   <div class="row subSectThree"></div>
</div>
```

**Note**: Insert `.row` after `.subSectOne`, `.subSectTwo` and `.subSectThree`, because the `contain`-property won't be trigger if you don`t do that.